# Windows Forms app consuming ASP.Net Web API using OpenID Connect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm creating a communication project that has 2 parts: a **Windows Forms client** app interacting with an **ASP.Net Web API** (note: **not** ASP.Net **Core**!), all written in C# on .Net Framework 4.7. Using this client, the user can post messages to and read them from the server (storage in SQL Server).

The idea is that the user can create a user using username+password or "any" (external) login provider (e.g. Google, Facebook, Microsoft Account, Twitter)... and of course, login afterwards using the same credentials. The API should preferably accept only calls from the client app.

I would like to use OpenID Connect, but IdentityServer4 only supports ASP.Net **Core**, whereas this isn't available at my hosting. In fact, I would be looking for the simplicity of something like OpenIddict, but again: no ASP.Net Core.
To be clear: the API will only be accessed by this 1 app (although there might be multiple concurrent instances of course - users using the app on different machines at the same time).

So, what are my questions:

1. Do I make some error in my basic reasoning about this project?
2. Is there any solution for implementing OpenID Connect (apart from "use ASP.Net Core", since this is not an option)?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth clarifying the 3 roles:
* UI - uses standard desktop logins and gets tokens
* API - validates access tokens
* Authorization Server - issues tokens

Identity model mplementation:
* UI: and API can both use IdentityModel library
* IdentityServer3 can be used to issue tokens

Understanding the messages can help clarify things - hope this points you in the right direction:
https://authguidance.com/2018/01/18/desktop-app-technical-workflow/